# url escaping in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

There are many discussion about URL escaping in Ruby, but unfortunately I didn't find an appropriate solution.

In general, `URI.escape` should do the job, but looks like it doesn't support all characters, for example it doesn't escape "[".

```
URI.parse(URI.escape("1111{3333"))
```

works well.

```
URI.parse(URI.escape("1111[3333"))
```

raises an exception.

I understand that "[" is not an eligible character in URL according to RFC, but when I enter it into the browser it takes it, and renders the page, so I need exactly the same behavior.

Do know any ready solution for escaping in Ruby?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I typically use

```
CGI.escape
```

to escape URI parameters.

```
require 'cgi'. 

CGI.escape('1111[3333')
=> "1111%5B3333"
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it does everything I need

Comment: the strange thing is, CGI.escape('1111 3333') = "1111+3333", which is should be "1111%203333", but actually links works also with "+"

Answer (score 3):

The character [ is a uri delimiter character and does not require escaping.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
section 2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters